# Jquery display matrix images one after one while page loading

Tags: jquery

I am having page with matrix product images, and i want to display that with jquery animation
showing one after one, i am using code like this

In default all images are in hidden. and following code for show each image with delay, so it will disply one after one

`$(".container img").each(function(i) {
$(this).delay(100*i).fadeIn(); 
});`

this works good, but what the problem is i have number of category that, while loading one category if user click on second category the remain first category images displayed in second category

how i can do this with out problem?

Comment: I have deleted my site url due to privacy and image for company

Comment: you can delete your site from google indexes while you're at it, if you don't want visitors :)

Comment: @DamienPirsy i am not saying don't want visitors... i don't want from here...are you thinking stack overflow as back linking site for us....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your category option button as `input type=button`. Just disable the buttons while loading images and after loading all images, remove the disabled from input like this:

```
$("div input").click(function() {
   $("div input").attr('disabled',true);

   $(".container img").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100*i).fadeIn();
   });

   $(".container img").promise().done(function() {
        $("div input").removeAttr('disabled');
   });

});
```

The jQuery promise function is used to find the end point of `$(".container img)` function. You can read more at http://api.jquery.com/promise/.

Comment: `promise()` is *entirely* redundant; `$(".container img")` returns immediately.